# Is it possible to integrate Nokia connectivity API with asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, nokia, connectivity

Is it possible to integrate Nokia connectivity API with asp.net? If so, How to get started? Any good reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by going to the Nokia website:

http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/bd896b31-92ba-4624-aa9d-ebf732e7cc0d/Nokia_PC_Suite_Connectivity_API_1_1.html